# Uninstalling new Relic on CentOS

Tags: uninstallation, newrelic-platform

I want to remove the package completely and start again as the server now has more 4 cores rather that 2, when new relic was first installed.

Have tried
yum erase newrelic-sysmond , but this still doesn't remove the package.

Have tried 
yum reinstall newrelic-sysmond , but this still doesn't pickup the new cores.

Have tried 
yum clean newrelic-sysmond , and get Error: invalid clean argument: 'newrelic-sysmond'

This also displayes
Package(s) newrelic-sysmond available, but not installed.

I want to remove it and reinstall brand new.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Installing / uninstalling software is not a programming activity.  This is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the uninstall instructions in our documentation which can be found [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/servers/new-relic-servers-linux/installation-configuration/servers-installation-other-linux#uninstall).

If you have any further questions please reach out to use at support.newrelic.com

Answer (score 0):

I had old version of new relic.
Those steps worked for me.
try to install again:

sudo rpm -Uvh http://yum.newrelic.com/pub/newrelic/el5/x86_64/newrelic-repo-5-3.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install newrelic-php5
sudo NR_INSTALL_SILENT=1 newrelic-install install

#disable service in ...etc/php.d/newrelic.ini (force set (wq!) newrelic.enabled = false)
then restart server (nginx)

newrelic-install purge
rm /usr/bin/newrelic-daemon
rm /etc/init.d/newrelic-daemon
rm /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/newrelic.so

killall newrelic-daemon
#restart nginx again

wait 12 hours(strange stuff, yeah)

https://api.newrelic.com/docs/#/Applications/delete_applications__id__json
by app id (you can see in apm services enter application and click under name app)
and take auth token here https://one.newrelic.com/admin-portal/api-keys/home
and run api command
Hope it will save someone a lot of time.